# No sound from embedded videos in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: sound, video

Dual boot machine... one HDD boots Ubuntu 16.04 LTS the other Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

When I'm playing embedded videos from Facebook (Firefox) in 18.04, there is NO SOUND. Testing the sound in **Settings** works fine. In 16.04, no problem with the sound, it's fine for the exact same videos.

Further info: Lack of sound also happens whenever using 'Videos' to play music or videos so do not have to have a browser open for the failure to occur. Task bar sound icon shows sound is NOT muted. Testing sound produces sounds from the speakers. But when ANY 'play' is called for, nothing comes out of the speakers. Dead quiet.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

First try to remove and install again drivers.

```
sudo apt-get remove alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

and force again alsa loading:

```
sudo alsa force-reload﻿
```

It wasn't enough for me, so I'd to remove the directory for creating a new one.

```
 mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse
```

Reboot for creating the new files automatically, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04.4 on an Asus M3A78 motherboard, there were times I had to use
`sudo alsa force-reload` to get the system to recognize the sound hardware.
Sometimes it took another reboot and a try or two before sound would work.

Comment: Tried that, got this message and no change. Tried shutting off the sound hardware, or leaving it on in Settings with no change...still no sound: Snip --- (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-rawmidi snd-seq-device snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer.